# select all users where count() equals a specific value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE COUNT(brand)='4'";
   $results = mysql_query($sql);
   $rows = mysql_fetch_array($results);
   print_r($rows);
```

the table cars has these columns:

```
id brand     price
0  bmw
1  corvette
2  mercedes
3  bmw
4  bmw
5  toyota
6  bmw
7  honda
8  lotus
```

this is what I am trying to do, return from the table `'cars'` every brand that has 4 different cars. In this example bmw has 4
4 different cars is 4 different rows with the same brand name.
so I am trying to echo the name of the brand where the total number of inventory is 4. 
I hope I made sense, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I tried 
SELECT * FROM cars LEFT JOIN users ON cars.user_id=users.user_id HAVING count(user_id) = 4   this is not working any ideas?

Comment: You have to use a `having` instead of `where`. results of aggregate functions aren't available yet when the `where` clauses are applied.

Comment: Just fyi: you should have a separate `brand` table, with `BrandName` and `BrandID`. Brand names are not constant.

Comment: thank you. I am trying to left join the users table so I can get the user's email who added the car listing. but it doesnt seem like its working. it returns a blank page. the code is on top

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT brand FROM cars GROUP BY brand HAVING COUNT(brand) = 4
```

***For you edit:***

```
SELECT t1.brand, t2.email 
FROM cars t1  
LEFT JOIN users t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
GROUP BY t1.brand HAVING COUNT(t1.brand) = 4
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM cars LEFT JOIN users ON cars.user_id=users.user_id HAVING count(user_id) = 4   this is not working any ideas?

Comment: @fogsy 1. You should provide enough detail to answer the question IN the question. 2. "not working" isn't very helpful. It probably is working. It is probably not doing what you expect it to do. 3. Try `SELECT brand` instead of `*`.

Comment: @Hamish sorry about the confusion, I am trying to do a LEFT join to the table users. ON cars.user_id=users.user_id . that way I can access users.email

Comment: You forgot the GROUP BY in your sql query.  Is the sql executing?
If not, try `SELECT brand FROM cars LEFT JOIN users ON cars.user_id=users.user_id GROUP BY brand HAVING count(*) = 4`

Comment: @fogsy put it in he question, don't bury it in the comments of one answer.

Comment: yes its executing this is what I have: SELECT brand FROM cars LEFT JOIN users ON cars.user_id=users.user_id GROUP BY brand HAVING COUNT(brand) = 4

Comment: Hmmm, you'll need to add more detail in your question to show the relationship between users and cars, and possibly brands if brands is in another table and the cars table actually has a brand_id. If the car brands aren't EXACTLY the same (i.e. there's a space at the end of one or one has uppercase) the GROUP BY won't work for you.

Comment: @yellottyellott I am doing a join on user_id columns,they are exactly the same.the sql you posted is exactly what I did beforehand but it returns a blank page. which I know there are results to my query

Comment: This query will only give you one email per brand. So if it's actually all the emails that you're after, this will only give you some of what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I think in the query like you have you need to use having

```
SELECT * FROM cars HAVING COUNT(brand)=4;
```

and group by depending on what you grouping

Answer (score 2):

You want perform an aggregate function (COUNT) on multiple rows at once. Pretty much anytime you want to perform multiple counts, you should think GROUP BY.

```
$sql = "SELECT brand FROM cars GROUP BY brand HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4";
```

If you do `SELECT *` in this query, you'll get 1 random row for each brand (probably the one with the lower id).

The HAVING clause will act as a WHERE on each of the groups.